# In TypeScript, Can I Declare Variables By Type Similar to C# Syntax?

Tags: typescript

I know I can declare a string array like so: `var words:string[] = ['first']`, but is there a way I can declare a string array like this: `string[] words = ['first']`? The second syntax for variable declaration is more clear to me and feels less confusing when dealing with large types. Plus I am more used to this style from Java and C#. Is there perhaps a TypeScript extension which I can install to enable this syntax?

Comment: Uhh, I don't think so. You typically can't change the syntax of a language just because you don't like it.

Comment: Someone should be able to theoretically do this, by forking https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript for example.

Comment: Perhaps I could write a webpack loader.

Comment: No, you can't, the syntax rules are very specific and clear. Yeah, you can do something that does that, or extend the language to support that, but (1) it sounds like way too much work for something as a personal taste, and (2) you'll need to keep changing things for every change in typescript which sounds like way too much work. You better just get used to the language syntax.